# MySQL query not working. not giving expected result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where there are 4 field to do query.

1. topup
2. totala
3. totalb
4. totalc

I am running the mysql query which is supposed to return 4 rows. But returning nothing. Following is my query:

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ".user." WHERE `topup` >'0' AND `totala`>='9' AND  `totalb`>='9' AND  `totalc`>='9'");
while($res=mysql_fetch_row($qry)){
    echo $res['0'];
}
```

what is the wrong? 
And main problem is if I run any one query

> eg: WHERE `totala` >='9'

then it is working, but not taking all query

Comment: what r u getting as result???

Comment: Looks like `echo $res['0']` should be `echo $res[0]'.

Comment: `".user." ` or `".$user."`? To avid problems like this use `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` scheme. And use PDO or Mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: ".user." is defined..

Comment: `user` is either a constant or an error, which is the case here?

Comment: @user2498559 so add `mysql_error()` part and replace `echo $res['0'];` with `print_R($res)`. If there is no error and no result then you have no row matching your criteria.

Comment: What's the resulting query?

Comment: Please remove ' from `totala`>='9' and other total. using '{value}' defines string. not integer.

Comment: does each row have their column totala,totalb and totalc value >= 9? please check the database..

Comment: use OR instead of AND to get results

Answer (score 0):

Your query will fetch rows in which all your condition are true simultaneously.

It will fetch the row with topup = 1 and totala = 10 and totalb = 10 and totalc = 10  but won't fetch the row topup = 0 and totala = 10 and totalb = 10 and totalc = 10 because of topup not greater than zero.

If you want to fetch row with ANY of this condition you need to use OR statement instead of AND.

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ".user." WHERE `topup` >'0' OR `totala`>='9' OR `totalb`>='9' OR `totalc`>='9'");
```